# How to name nested routes parameters in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I've the following nested route:

```
resources :carts, only: [:show, :update, :create], param: :token do
  resources :items, :controller => :cartitems, except: [:new, :edit], param: :product_id
end
```

This generates

```
GET    /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:cart_token/items(.:format)             cartitems#index
POST   /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:cart_token/items(.:format)             cartitems#create
GET    /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:cart_token/items/:product_id(.:format) cartitems#show
PATCH  /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:cart_token/items/:product_id(.:format) cartitems#update
PUT    /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:cart_token/items/:product_id(.:format) cartitems#update
DELETE /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:cart_token/items/:product_id(.:format) cartitems#destroy
...
```

I want to remove the controller part in the `resources :items` parameters. That means: I want to rename the `:cart_token` parameter to `:token`. Just like:

```
GET    /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:token/items(.:format)             cartitems#index
POST   /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:token/items(.:format)             cartitems#create
GET    /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:token/items/:product_id(.:format) cartitems#show
PATCH  /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:token/items/:product_id(.:format) cartitems#update
PUT    /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:token/items/:product_id(.:format) cartitems#update
DELETE /api/merchants/:merchant_id/carts/:token/items/:product_id(.:format) cartitems#destroy
...
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you please edit with the route list you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if it's the best way to do that, but I got the routes you expected there by:

```
scope 'api/mechantes/:merchant_id/carts/:token' do
  resources :items, :controller => :cartitems, except: [:new, :edit], param: :product_id
end
```

Hope this can helps. Good luck!